# Error 1366 sent MariaDb version 10.1.48 on wrong strings

Tags: mariadb

In PHP, i reproduce the problem with this command as an example, introducing some junk chars in the data i want to store :

$my_val = 'blabla' . chr(0xC2) . chr(0x94) . 'blabla';
$query = "UPDATE `my_table` SET `my_field`='" . $my_val  . "' WHERE `id`='1'";

my_database, my_table, and my_field are ALL set to utf8mb4 and this cannot be changed.

I would like MariaDb to accept the wrong chars instead of returning systematic 1366 (Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x94b  ' on this query.)

This problem is new on this MariaDb version : everything was ok on previous version.

I tried to add the IGNORE command to my query, but it ignore the error without writing the data.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Used prepared statements and this prevents some errors, and also if you are inserting into a utf8mb4 table, character string must be legal utf8.

Comment: `IGNORE` only ignores duplicate keys, it doesn't ignore invalid data.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately preparation needs to filter utf8 errors which is tricky.

Comment: maybe `varbinary` is a better data choice then.

Comment: C298 should be the valid UTF-8 sequence for code point U+0098 "Start of String".

How is your MariaDB connection set up, did you e.g. run `SET NAMES utf8` after connecting? As this looks like a conversion error to me.

Regarding the "only starting with 10.1" behavior: more recent versions have become more strict when it comes to data validation, but this may also due to changed config parameter default settings.

Hard to tell what's going wrong here when seeing just that one statement, and not how the connection was set up and how the server is configured

Comment: Yes, SET NAMES UTF8 has been implemented.
My problem is mainly due to this new version of MariaDb attached with Debian 11 which rejects that and cause update failures.

The fact is that the data we receive can have problems in their strings and my goal is to store these odd chars or char sequences replaced with a '?'